# Authentication error when requests go through proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, networking, proxy

I have the following code that makes a web request through a proxy server. I sniffed the network traffic with wireshark on the server and found that I get the following error when the request is made:

Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.\n

The authentication should be running through NTLM.

Can anyone help please?

```
    //... CALL THE CODE
    string url = String.Format("http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx/GetCultureInfo?Currency={0}", CurrencyTo.Text);
    returnValue = GetResponseValue(url);
    //...

    private static string GetResponseValue(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = InitialiseWebRequest(url);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

        string returnValue = xmlDoc.Root.Value;
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static WebRequest InitialiseWebRequest(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyLogin"]))
        {
            string proxyUrl = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyUrl"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyPort"]))
            {
                proxyUrl += ":" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyPort"];
            }

            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl);

            // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the Proxy property of request object.
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyLogin"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyPassword"]);

            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyLogin"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["proxyPassword"]);

            CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();

            credentialCache.Add(new Uri(url), "NTML", networkCredential);

            request.Credentials = credentialCache;
            request.Proxy = proxy;

            return request;
        }

        return request;
    }
```

Comment: While you were sniffing, have you noticed if the correct credentials (username/password I guess is how you authenticate) are going to the proxy?

Comment: How do I go about checking this? I had assumed that it wouldn't be possible to check the username/password due to security reasons

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the username had the domain prefixed and the password expired and wasn't updated in the config.

After a full day of looking past the obvious I got a lightbulb moment.